# Extracting certificate issuer and subject common name using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, authenticode

I want to use a PowerShell one-liner to extract the signing certificate issuer and subject's common names, but I am not able to get it working. Currently, I have:

```
Get-AuthenticodeSignature .\test.exe | ForEach-Object { ($_.SignerCertificate.Thumbprint, ($_.SignerCertificate.Issuer -split ',' | Where-Object { $_ -like 'CN=*' }), ($_.SignerCertificate.Subject -split ',' | Where-Object { $_ -like 'CN=*' }), $_.SignerCertificate.NotAfter) -join ',' }
```

This code does not work for cases when the common name itself contains a comma. For example, "MyCompany, Inc."

Comment: Change your `-Split ','` to `-Split ',.+?='` and that should take care of it. That will make sure that it only splits on a comma that has a "Designator=" type thing right after it.

Comment: That does not seem to work. The other suggestion worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
Get-AuthenticodeSignature .\test.exe | 
ForEach-Object { 
((($_.SignerCertificate.Issuer -split ', O=')[0] -split '=')[1],  
(($_.SignerCertificate.Subject -split ', O=')[0] -split '=')[1] 
) -join ', '
}
```

Of course you can remove the line breaks  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`